# In Powerpoint with vbscript how to adjust the displayed range in an embedded OLE xls object?

Tags: excel, vbscript, powerpoint

My problem is that I'm incorporating xls-sheets into a powerpoint-presentation. Sometimes the last 3 columns are not visible in the object. They are there if you double-click the object and look into it in Excel though.
I would like a way in vbscript to set the range that the embedded-object icon should display.
(That is possible to do manually by double-clicking the object and drag the small black squares positioned in the middle of each side of the object after double-clicking.)

I've been trying for 2 days to solve this little problem. I've tried OLEFormat and this http://msofficeautomation.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/add-excel-sheet-via-addoleobject-into-powerpoint/ without any luck.
I've tried to record a macro in Word since I don't have the record-functionality in ppt but when recording a macro you cannot redefine the range displayed in the object. :-(

I attach a small example done as a macro in powerpoint itself adding an xlsx-file named C:\temp\addOLEObject_problem\Book1.xlsx

```
Sub AddObject()

 Set PPSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 16)
 Set objShapeOLE = PPSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, , , ,"C:\temp\addOLEObject_problem\Book1.xlsx", False)
 ' Set objShapeOLE = PPSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(0, 0, , , , ".\Book1.xlsx", False)
 ' Resize to fill the slide
 '  ******check if width or height of the picture is larger than the slide*******
 defaultWidth = objShapeOLE.Width
 defaultHeight = objShapeOLE.Height
 wRatio = PPSlide.Master.Width / objShapeOLE.Width 'Will be smaller and smaller the more resizing that is needed of the larger picture
 hRatio = PPSlide.Master.Height / objShapeOLE.Height ' if >1 no resize is needed

 resizeRatio = 1
 If wRatio < hRatio Then
     resizeRatio = wRatio
 Else
     resizeRatio = hRatio
 End If
 objShapeOLE.Width = resizeRatio * objShapeOLE.Width

 '????How to set the range being displayed in the object?????

End Sub
```

Brgds
Andy